# How can change my hardcoded data of a card carousel to dynamic data from api response -Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

Good day. Please I am have a challenge on how to change my hardcoded data to dynamic from the api. The response to the API returns success but populating the card carousel is the challenge I am having. I keep on getting error "type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'List<Map<String, String>>'"'

This my Api request:

```
  SharedPreferences _prefs;

  void getCategories() async {

    try {
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var _categoryService = CategoryService();
      var result =
          await _categoryService.getCategories(_prefs.getString('token'));
      var categories = json.decode(result.body);

      print('categories');
      print(categories);

      List<Map<String, String>> foodCategories = categories;

    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

This is my list variable with hard coded data:

```
 final List<Map<String, String>> foodCategories = [
    {
      'name': 'Rice Planting',
      'image': 'images/Icon-001.png',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Harvesting',
      'image': 'images/Icon-002.png',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Machineries',
      'image': 'images/Icon-003.png',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Rice Products',
      'image': 'images/Icon-004.png',
    }
  ];
```

And this is my screen:

```
  Container(
              height: 105,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                top: 20.0,
                bottom: 25.0,
              ),
              child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    left: 20.0,
                  ),
                  itemCount: this.foodOptions.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    Map<String, String> option = this.foodOptions[index];
                    return Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35.0),
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: 70,
                            height: 70,
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                Radius.circular(5.0),
                              ),
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: AssetImage(
                                  option['image'],
                                ),
                              ),
                              boxShadow: [
                                BoxShadow(
                                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                                  color: Colors.grey[300],
                                  offset: Offset(6.0, 6.0),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            option['name'],
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
```

My basic challenge is how to switch this hardcoded data of **foodCategories **  to

```
 var categories = json.decode(result.body); which is from the API. any suggestion I will highly appreciate. The Api returns a json with image and category name
```

this is the UI picture

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Declare this List in your screen widget:

```
final List<Map<String, String>> foodCategories = [
    {
      'name': 'Rice Planting',
      'image': 'images/Icon-001.png',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Harvesting',
      'image': 'images/Icon-002.png',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Machineries',
      'image': 'images/Icon-003.png',
    },
    {
      'name': 'Rice Products',
      'image': 'images/Icon-004.png',
    }
  ];
```

Add this method to your screen widget:

```
void getCategories() async {

    try {
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var _categoryService = CategoryService();
      var result =
          await _categoryService.getCategories(_prefs.getString('token'));
      var categories = json.decode(result.body);

      print('categories');
      print(categories);

      setState(() {
          foodCategories = categories;
      });
      

    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
```

and call the method in initState:

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
getCategories();
  }
```

Comment: ok @anas_nadeem please I will give it a try and revert back. Thank you very much

Comment: Also convert List<Map<String, String>> to List.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a state management tool for this use case, like Provider, on flutter.dev there is a nice explanation on how to use it [Simple app state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).

Basically you wrap the api call inside a **provider** class and every time data comes from the api it **notify** the **consumers** that are using the provider.

**Steps:**

1 - Add the provider dependency to your pubspec.yaml.

```yaml
name: my_name
description: Blah blah blah.

# ...

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  provider: ^6.0.0

dev_dependencies:
  # ...
```

2 - Create a provider for your desire state, in this case the list of categories

```dart
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../category_service.dart';

class CategoriesProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  List<Map<String, String>> foodCategories = [];
  bool loading = false;

  var _prefs;

  void getCategories() async {
    try {
      loading = true;

      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var _categoryService = CategoryService();
      var result =
      await _categoryService.getCategories(_prefs.getString('token'));
      var categories = json.decode(result.body);

      print('categories');
      print(categories);

      List<Map<String, String>> foodCategories = categories;

      loading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception();
    }
  }
}
```

3 - Create an instance of CategoriesProvider and add it to the widget tree near to the desired carrossel widget, you can read more about where to insert the provider on this link https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

```dart
void main() {
  runApp(
    ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => CategoriesProvider (),
      child: const MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}
```

4 - In the stateful widget you need to create a instance of the CategoriesProvider to retrieve the data from the api.

```dart
class _MyApp extends State<MyApp> {
  late CategoriesProvider categoriesProvider;
  @override
  void initState() {
    categoriesProvider = Provider.of(context, listen: false);
    categoriesProvider.getCategories();
    
    super.initState();
  }
```

5 - On the screen widget you can wrap your widget with a Consumer widget to retrieve the data from the provider, replacing on your example the this.foodOptions with the categories defined early on the provider class.

```dart
Consumer<CategoriesProvider>(
        builder: (context, provider, _) => Container(
          height: 105,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
            top: 20.0,
            bottom: 25.0,
          ),
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20.0,
              ),
              itemCount: provider.foodCategories.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                Map<String, String> option = provider.foodCategories[index];
                return Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 35.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 70,
                        height: 70,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(5.0),
                          ),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: AssetImage(
                              option['image'],
                            ),
                          ),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              blurRadius: 10.0,
                              color: Colors.grey[300],
                              offset: Offset(6.0, 6.0),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        option['name'],
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              }),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: please can you show a me a quick a example with this code. I've never used provider before.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: you can get an idea from the steps above, and get a full example on https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple